# How can I access an external hard drive through Ubuntu Linux?

Tags: mount

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Mounting an external USB drive via VirtualBox?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/154485/mounting-an-external-usb-drive-via-virtualbox)

I have a Western Digital external HD of around 2TB; Windows 7 for some reason no longer allows me to open it: when I plug it into my laptop (via a USB 2.0 port), Windows either does nothing or asks me to format the drive because it doesn't recognize the file system. So I am trying to see if I can access the files in Ubuntu.

I am running Ubuntu through VirtualBox. Before starting Ubuntu, I went into the USB settings for the Ubuntu virtual machine, and selected the external hard drive (VBox sees it). Then I started Ubuntu. Here is the print out of `fdisk -l`:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 91.3 GB, 91268055040 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 11096 cylinders, total 178257920 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000d5f79

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048   174583807    87290880   83  Linux
/dev/sda2       174585854   178255871     1835009    5  Extended
/dev/sda5       174585856   178255871     1835008   82  Linux swap / Solaris

Disk /dev/sdb: 2000.4 GB, 2000396746752 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 243201 cylinders, total 3907024896 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00020fc3

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *        2048  3907024895  1953511424    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

I believe the external drive is the bottom one, sdb1, but I have no idea how to access it. Is it already mounted or do I have to mount it manually? If Windows 7 did not recognize it, will the same problem occur in Ubuntu?